# How to prove that : the graph of function $f$ is symmetric w.r.t. point $I=(a,b)$ iff $ f(2a-x)+f(x)= 2b$.

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Source : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RHiaIKJeBA , claiming that function $f$ is symmetric w.r.t. a point $I=(a,b)$ iff $ f(2a-x)+f(x)= 2b$.

[image]

Symmetry with respect to $O=(0,0)$ is defined by $ f(-x)= -f(x)$.

Saying that function $f$ is symmetric with respect to a point $I=(a,b)$ is equivalent to saying that in a cartesian coordinate system centered at $I$, function $g(x)= f(x-a) + b$ is symmetric with respect to the origin.

So we should have  $g(-x)= -g(x)$, that is $ f(-x-a)+b = -(f(x-a)+b) =  -f(x-a) -b$.

Manipulating this last expression, I get :

$ f(-x-a)+b = -f(x-a)-b$

$\iff f(-x-a) +f(x-a) = -2b$

$\iff -f(-x-a) -f(x-a) = 2b$

Not quite identical to the desired formula.

Comment: Symmetry: f(a+u)=f(a-u).  Let x=a-u, so u=a-x.  Result: f(x)=f(2a-x).  Why complicate it?

Comment: @VinceVickler FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(-x-a)%2Bf(x-a)%3D-2b%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24f(2a-x)%2Bf(x)%3D2b%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Asymmetric&p=2), I found [center of symmetry formula](/q/550091), where this [answer](/a/722223) uses the $f(x+a)-b$ formula I give in $(1)$ in my [answer](/a/4602167) below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea. However, note that to get the new function $g(x)$ to be symmetric with respect to the origin means we need to shift the coordinates left by $a$ and down by $b$, so it'll actually be

$$g(x) = f(x + a) - b \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

i.e., you have the opposite signs for the $a$ and $b$ terms (with \eqref{eq1A} giving $g(0) = f(a)-b = b - b = 0$, as required). Using the general $g(-y) = -g(y)$, similar to what you did, we next have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f(-y+a)-b & = -(f(y+a) - b) \\
f(-y+a) - b & = -f(y+a) + b \\
f(-y+a) + f(y+a) & = 2b
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Using $x = y+a \; \to \; -y = a -x \; \to \; -y+a = 2a -x$, we then get

$$f(2a-x) + f(x) = 2b$$

as the linked video claims. Note this gives the $\implies$ part of the claim, with the $\impliedby$ part coming from that the actions on the expressions above are all reversible.

Comment: I see you seem to use the criterion  ( for symmetry) $ g(-y) = -g(y)$  . Is the criterion $ g(-x)= -g(x)$ wrong? Or do I misinterpret what you're doing?

Comment: @VinceVickler I just use a different letter there, i.e., $y$, so that I will end up with $x$ at the end, to match what the video used. Nonetheless, your criterion is also correct. Using it, then switching the variables around in my answer gives us $f(2a-y)+f(y)=2b$ instead. Since $y$ is just a *dummy* variable, we can give it any name., e.g., we could call it $x$ instead, to then get $f(2a-x)+f(x)=2b$. I did it that particular way in my answer as I thought it'd be a bit simpler, and possibly less confusing. Nonetheless, perhaps I was wrong, at least on the latter part.